# Partitions in Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, partitions-for-integration

Help me to solve it. I don't understand this knowledge!!! Thansk so much ^^

Let f(x)=|x| , [-1,1] . Have P={ x0=-1 < x1< ... <xn = 1}, xi - xi-1 = 2/n. Find: L(f,P) and U(f,P)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cbof.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please do not post homework questions with absolutely zero effort. Besides, have you searched the site for very similar questions?